# Substituting values from one table into another

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

**If you are going to downvote this, please at least give a reason why.**

I'm sorry if the answer to my question is already on here, the issue I have is that I'm new to SQL and don't really know what to look for, which makes it hard to find the answers on google or SE.

I'll quickly describe what it is I'm trying to do.

I have a master table, lets call it *master* which tracks performances of teams.

I have another table called *teams* which has two columns, the team name and a three letter acronym (TLA) for the team. The three letter acronym is unique for every team.

In the master table, the teams are stored as their TLAs for simplicity and to keep the table neat and compact.

---

My question is this:

How can I get the database to return the full team name when it comes across the acronym each time in the *master* table?

Using

```
WHERE master.team1=teams.teamid;
```

Does substitute the names, but for each entry in *master* I have 2 teams (team1,team2).

I would like to be able to return the whole row with both teams in their full names and any other information I would like to pull from that row.

---

Again, I'm sorry if this isn't making much sense, I'm very new to MySQL and am unsure of what way to word my question / look up answers.

Many thanks in advance and have a nice Sunday y'all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` to the teams table twice, something like:

```
SELECT m.*,t1.team_name,t2.team_name
FROM master m
JOIN teams t1
  ON m.team1 = t1.TLA
JOIN teams t2
  ON m.team2 = t2.TLA
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a go now. I didn't know what JOIN was, but can now look up the syntax on it and will try to work this out.

Comment: I have managed to get this to display the full team names (thank you) however the team1 and team2 columns are still present from my master table. Is it possible to strip these? Thanks again and sorry for being a noob.

Comment: Instead of `m.*` choose only the fields you want to return from your table.  ie: `m.this, m.that, m.otherthing`

Comment: Thank you very much, that has sorted it. Have a nice day!